# JsonIgnore not working with Spring Security Users and Roles

Tags: java, spring-security, jackson, spring-session, jackson-databind

I Have user, role, and privilege tables configured with ManytoMany relationships. Security configuration validates user credentials against database and checks user roles to access the URL. Since roles and users joined with Many-Many relation, I put `@JsonIgnore` annotation on child side to prevent StackOverflow error.

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Collection<User> users;
```

on parent side I configured join table and join columns

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Collection<Role> roles;
```

When the user tries to log in I see an error **Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate com.springtesting.model.User.toString()**. JsonIgnore should prevent this infinite recursion and I am not sure why it's not doing this.

**User.Java**

```
package com.springtesting.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;


@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_profile_id")
    private UserProfile userProfile;


    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(String username, String password, Boolean active, UserProfile userProfile)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.active = active;
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }

}
```

**Role.Java**

```
package com.springtesting.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "name",nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Collection<User> users;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "role_privilege",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "privilege_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Collection<Privilege> privileges;

}
```

**Privilege.Java**

```
package com.springtesting.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "privilege")
public class Privilege implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Collection<Role> roles;
}
```

SecurityConfig.Java

```
package com.springtesting.security.config;


import com.springtesting.security.MyUserDetailsService;
import com.springtesting.security.handlers.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.springtesting.security.handlers.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.springtesting.security.handlers.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.springtesting.security.providers.CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository;
import org.springframework.session.Session;
import org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.EnableJdbcHttpSession;
import org.springframework.session.security.SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.session.security.web.authentication.SpringSessionRememberMeServices;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    private final MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /*@Autowired
    private final FindByIndexNameSessionRepository<Session> sessionRepository = null;*/

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService)
    {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
    {
        auth.authenticationProvider(getDaoAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider getDaoAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider=new CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(getBCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    /* BCrypt strength should 12 or more*/
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getBCryptPasswordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
                    .antMatchers("/users/**").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.Admin)
                    .antMatchers("/admin**").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.Admin)
                    .antMatchers("/profile/**").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.User)
                    .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.ApiUser)
                    .antMatchers("/dba/**").hasAuthority(AuthorityConstants.Dba)
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                    .httpBasic()
            .and()
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .successHandler(new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                        .failureHandler(new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                        .permitAll()
            .and()
                    .logout()
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
                        .permitAll()
            .and()
                    .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(springSessionRememberMeServices());


        http.sessionManagement()
                        .invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
                        .sessionFixation()
                        .migrateSession()
                        .maximumSessions(1);
                        //.sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringSessionRememberMeServices springSessionRememberMeServices()
    {
        SpringSessionRememberMeServices rememberMeServices = new SpringSessionRememberMeServices();
        // optionally customize
        rememberMeServices.setRememberMeParameterName("remember-me");
        rememberMeServices.setValiditySeconds(86000);

        return rememberMeServices;
    }


   /* @Bean
    SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry()
    {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(this.sessionRepository);
    }*/

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher()
    {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

    @Bean("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

**MyUserDetailsService.java**

```
package com.springtesting.security;

import com.springtesting.model.Privilege;
import com.springtesting.model.Role;
import com.springtesting.model.User;
import com.springtesting.repo.RoleRepository;
import com.springtesting.repo.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService
{
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MyUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository)
    {
        this.userRepository=userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        User user=userRepository.findByUsername(username);
        if(user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Could not find Username");
        return new MyUserPrincipal(user,getGrantedAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }


    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles)
    {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role  : roles)
        {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }


    /*  private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Collection<String> privileges)
   {
       List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
       for (String privilege : privileges)
       {
           authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(privilege));
       }
       return authorities;
   }
    private List<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roles)
    {
        return getGrantedAuthorities(getPrivileges(roles));
    }

    private List<String> getPrivileges(Collection<Role> roles)
    {
        List<String> privileges = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Privilege> collection = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Role role : roles)
        {
            collection.addAll(role.getPrivileges());
        }
        for (Privilege item : collection)
        {
            privileges.add(item.getName());
        }
        return privileges;
    }
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. When I use Lombok for getters, setters, and toString() methods, it tries to loop through roles/users presented in child table which then causes infinite recursion. Overriding `toString()`default implementation solved my issue